# How to communicate with GUI from another class

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I have problem with understanding how to communicate with GUI from another class.

We have one class, whitch creates Frame:

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    javax.swing.JLabel label;

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
        label=sampleLabel;
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        sampleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        sampleLabel.setText("anotherText");
        getContentPane().add(sampleLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 60, -1, -1));

        pack();
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel sampleLabel;

}

Main class instantiate CreateFrame and tryes to overwrite label text:

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        frame.label.setText("anotherText");
    }
}
```

Of course, above code doesn't work. But I am new in Java and I need somehow to access label from another class (as seen in example...)

**Newest edit: Above code does work :) Hope helps...**

Following pictures are showing the same frame. Only thing whitch changed was JLabel text.

[image: Sample picture]

Please help.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? Just to have a class that creates JFrames and another class instantiates it? Your class that creates JFrames will have to have a constructor that takes in Strings for Labels and everytime you instantiate it you can give it a different label.

Comment: I am also curious about how this would be answered by someone with experience.

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3tvfu8/

Comment: I just want to build simple frame with one label in one class and somehow access and change text of this label from different class (situated in different package maybe...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to be able to change the label by accessing its setText() method. All you have to do is the following (keeping everything else the same):

```
public void makeFrames() {
        CreateFrame frame = new CreateFrame("Label1");
        frame.label.setText("new Label");
}
```

The following is a quick hack to see the change of label in action:

```
public class Main {

    JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Main object = new Main();
                object.makeFrames();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeFrames() {
        final CreateFrame frame = new CreateFrame("Label1");

        button = new JButton("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.label.setText("new Label");
            }
        });
        frame.frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
    }
}
```

The label changes to the new one when you click the button.

**EDIT 2: (Changes made to main(), button declared static so it could be accessed from within main()**

```
public class Main {

    static JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final CreateFrame frameFromMain = new CreateFrame("Label1");

                button = new JButton("Click");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frameFromMain.label.setText("new Label");
                    }
                });
                frameFromMain.frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Remember that you access label in CreateFrame class just like you access any other member of a class. You could access it directly if you declared your variables static like so:

```
public class CreateFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    static JLabel label;
    // the rest of the class remains the same
}

public class Main {

    static JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CreateFrame frameFromMain = new CreateFrame("Label1");

                button = new JButton("Click");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        CreateFrame.label.setText("new Label");
                    }
                });
                frameFromMain.frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:**

If you don't want the button, delete the code for the button and do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CreateFrame frameFromMain = new CreateFrame("Label1");
                CreateFrame.label.setText("new Label"); // accessing label directly from main()

            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT 4: Using the OP's code:**

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    javax.swing.JLabel label;

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
        label=sampleLabel;
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        sampleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sampleLabel.setText("anotherText");
        add(sampleLabel);
        pack();
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel sampleLabel;
}
```

And then your main() would look like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       final TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        frame.label.setText("Text From Main");
    }
}
```

I have made minimal changes. This code runs perfectly and does what you ask. I got rid of your "getContentPane" because you don't need it in Java 6, 7. I also got rid of your Layout settings because I myself am not familiar with them. You need to learn to import java classes.

It seems like you are in very early stages of learning Java. I would suggest you stick to command-line programs until you figure out how Java works before moving on to Swing.

Comment: I see, that my english is probably on really low level :( Thanks a lot for your answer, but it is not what i was looking for. I will try to make it more clear: Question is how to access JLabel instance .setText() method from different class/thread. This different class is e.g. located in different package...

Comment: @BigT "Question is how to access JLabel instance .setText() method from different class/thread". I'm trying to understand but still can't. Lemme know if I got it right. You want to access the setText() method from JLabel class and change the label on an already running frame? Or do you want to be able to create new frames with the label that you give them through setText() method?

Comment: @BigT See the text below "EDIT:" in my answer and lemme know if that's what you want.

Comment: In your example - is there any way how to access 'label' from inside main() function? - that is what I had on my mind. Thanks a lot. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @BigT I'm glad its helping you somewhat. I created an extra method to keep things neat. But you can instantiate the class that creates the frame inside main and then access is exactly like I did in the createFrames() method. See below "EDIT 2:" in about 3 minutes or so.

Comment: I am sorry, please do not waste your time with that question anymore, because I think that maybe I am not abble to express my self in right way... I do not need any button im my class. Here is sample of your first example code:public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           
            public void run() {
                Main object = new Main();
                object.makeFrames();
            }
        }); //here is the place where I want direct manipulation with label...
    }  Thanks a lot for your time...Srry:(

Comment: @BigT You can remove the button if you want. Its not that hard. Direct manipulation of the label is already explained. Set the JLabel as static in your class that  creates the frame and the label and then access the label directly with CreateFrame.label.setText() from your main. My code is only supposed to be an example, not something you can directly add to your project. I only added the button to show you that the label on an already existing frame was changing, which is what you seem to want. See my EDIT 3:

Comment: HI, I completly rebuilt my "Intro". I believe that now, it is much more clearer. Thanks for your time... Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @BigT See my EDIT 4. I have used your code and it runs perfectly. Do read my comments below the code. If this still doesn't answer your question then I'm afraid I can't help and hope someone else would be able to. If it does help then I'd appreciate upvotes and accepted answer because this took a lot out of me :)

Comment: It is the result of 10 hour session at one simple problem. All the time I had the solution in front of my nose, but i was not able to see it :) Nickecarlo thanks a lot for your time, for your answers and for everything. Paradox is that I have already coded for about 4000 lines of my project in Java (System of identification and authentization of speaker) :) But that simple problem tooks me all day, till now. I try to upvote (it is my first question so i believe that i will find the right button :) ) Greetings to Argentina :)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have enought reputation... But I promise, when I get reputation 15 i will upvote for your advice... So thanks a lot again.

Comment: @BigT Phew. Don't worry about the upvote. I'm just glad the answer helped. :-) And greetings to you and to wherever you're from too. Have fun with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a way to do it by using JSON http requests.  I found [a web article](http://icewalker2g.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/using-json-in-java-swing/) with some ideas to start with although you will need to implement the http requests in the GUI and also implement the JSON server to serve the request responses.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but this is not what i meant. Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. I just want to build simple frame with one label in one class and somehow access and change text of this label from different class (situated in different package maybe...).